# C define/global variable which depends on something else

Tags: c

I am programming a little game in C for university and I am stuck on a point. I have (in header file) this struct:

```
typedef struct{

    game_element field[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
    int n;
    int m;

}battlefield;
```

and I want to set globally MAXBOMBS value as (n*m)/100. (with n and m fields of the struct above).
I tried define as follow:

```
#define MAXBOMBS (n*m)/100
```

but i encountered an error when I call it in some other functions. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How could you use `n` or `m` when they have no value? You don't even have a variable of the structure? Unless you create another global variable of the `battlefield` type with already initialized `n` and `m` members they can't be used to declare other global variables.

Comment: Please add some more flesh on the bones: what is your `#define` and how did you try to use it?

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mcve], to make helping you easier.

Comment: What would you expect the result to be if you have two instances of `battlefield` with distinct/different values of their `m` and `n` members?

Answer (score 1):

Macros are *replaced* in the source code by the preprocessor. So everywhere you use `MAXBOMBS` they will quite literally be replaced by `(n*m)/100`. That is of course not correct, unless you happen to have two variables in scope named `n` and `m`. But it will not be any `n` or `m` from the structure you want.

You could solve this two ways: Either a function-like macro

```
#define MAXBOMBS(s) (((s).n * (s).m) / 100)
```

You can use it like

```
battlefield f;
// Code that initializes the n and m members
some_function(MAXBOMBS(f));
```

Or you create an actual function which takes a `battlefield` structure as argument, and does the calculation needed and return the result:

```
static inline int maxbombs(battlefield bf)
{
    return (bf.n * bf.m) / 100;
}
```

I recommend the solution using a function.